# read part of a file after writing

Tags: ruby, file-io, io

After creating a file and populating data into it, before close, need read part data and
  calculate the checksum. The issue is you cant read the data before close the file. Code
  snippet is as follows.

My question is how to create a file, write data, read part of the file, then close it? One
  possible  solution is using a buffer before write to the file, but it is not convenient if
  the file is big, such as MB, GB, TB, PB.

```
  begin
  File.open(@f_name,"w+") do |file|

    @f_old_size.times do
      file.write "1"
    end

    file.flush
    file.sync

    #################
    # read file fails
    # before close
    #################
    while line = file.gets
      puts line
    end

  end
  rescue => err
   puts "Exception: #{err}"
  end

  #####################
  # read file successfully
  # after close it
  #####################
  File.open(@f_name,"r") do |file|
    line = file.gets
    puts line
  end
```

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but those look like normal stdio `fopen` flags..  Instead of using 'w', why don't you use 'a' to open the file for append (reading and writing)?

Comment: in ruby, "a" mode is not readable

Comment: Files are typically locked while they are being read or written to. It's possible, although tricky, error prone, and not considered good practice, to read/write from a file at once.

Comment: Why do you need to get the checksum before closing the file? If you want to write the checksum into the file, then you don't get the checksum of the file, the checksum itself would change the checksum. If you want data + checksum, then you could store the data in memory and store data and checksum in one step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you're running into is that [Ruby IO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html) reads through the file and keeps track of where in the file it is.   After you've written out your data, the 'seek head' of the IO object is at the bottom of the file.   When you ask it for the next line, because it's at the bottom, you don't get anything.

If you change your code to include a `file.rewind` as such, it works:

```
#################
# read file fails
# before close
#################
file.rewind  # <--  THIS IS THE ADDED LINE
while line = file.gets
  puts line
end
```

The `#rewind` method sets the 'seek head' back to the beginning of the file, which is what you're looking to do.